# Is it possible to update my XCode/Objective-C program or offer patches?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, patch

I'm looking to find information on how to update my XCode program that has been released. Is there an easy way to go about this? What if it includes changes to my Core Data Model?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly you didn't make it clear in your question whether you are using MacOS or iOS.

iOS is pretty straightforward (you simply update the app within the app store).

MacOS has a bit more diversity. If it's on the app store, you can update it there.

If it's a standalone app, you can use open source frameworks like [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) (<-- which I've linked for you) which notify the user that a new version of your program is available to download and gives them the ability to click a button to download & install the update.